# Is it possible to chain two readers in spring batch?

Tags: spring-batch

What I want is to read the value from the database in the first reader,
The goal is to pass the value as a parameter to the second leader.

ex) 100 row table A
firstPagingReader 0 ~ 10 row -> second Reader -> processor -> writer
firstPagingReader 11 ~ 20 row -> second Reader -> processor -> writer

I want to operate sequentially like this.

I tried a lot of searches, but couldn't find a suitable answer.

In this case, is there no choice but to handle it with a tasklet?

Comment: It is mandatory that the processing happens in sequence? Because if not, a partitioned step would be a good option for this case.